# stopping event from code C#, call event by user not by code

Tags: c#, wpf

Sorry, this may be a duplicate question, but I couldnot understand the solutions already provided in different answers.

I have created a mp3 player in a different manner, it plays one mp3 file at a time but one listbox have the chapters, which is not only handling to move position of that particular mp3 but also changes a picturebox image. Now somewhere I need to change the selection of the listbox  from a seekbar but dont want to fire the following event of; 
        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Boolean with class scope called something like isProcessing. Set it to true. Do your work, then set it to false. Warp your event in the Boolean:

```
bool isProcessing = true;
private void switchControls(){
   isProcessing = true;
   //do work;
   isProcessing = false;
}
private void MyControl.OnEvent(object sender, EventArgs e){
   if(!isProcessing){
      //what you would normally do
   }
}
```

OR....

Deregister the event, the re-register it

```
private void switchControls(){
     myButton1.OnClick -= myButtonClick;
     //do work
     myButton1.OnClick += myButtonClick;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Shannon, I have applied the Deregister and Re-register method, which worked wonderful for me. thanks once again.

Comment: No problem - please remember to select this answer so it does not remain open. Glad I could help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

One way to inhibit your selection indexed change event doing its normal way is to use a boolean flag. Also, make sure that this inhibition does not stay around when some exception is raised:

```
private bool inhibit = true;

private void doSomeProcessWithInhibit()
{
    try
    {
        inhibit = true;

        // processing comes here    
    }
    // if something goes wrong, make sure other functionality is not blocked
    finally
    {
        inhibit = false;
    }
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // fast return to reduce nesting
    if (inhibit)
        return;

    // do event handling stuff here
}
```

P.S. Try to use meaningful names for controls (check `listBox1`). You will thank yourself when revisiting the code and/or [others have to](http://www.osnews.com/story/19266/WTFs_m).

Comment: actually I am an entry level programmer Alexei, I will try to work with your given suggestions in the future. Thank you for your reply.